# Which is the best way to find element in array column in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a array column on which i find text from it and form a dataframe. Which is the better way among the below 2 options?
**Option 1**

```
val texts = Seq("text1", "text2", "text3")
 val df = mainDf.select(col("*"))
      .withColumn("temptext", explode($"textCol"))
      .where($"temptext".isin(texts: _*))
```

And since it has added and extra column "temptext" and increased duplicate rows by exploding

```
  val tempDf = df.drop("temptext").dropDuplicates("Root.Id")  // dropDuplicates does not work since I have passed nested field
```

**vs**

**Option 2**

```
val df = mainDf.select(col("*"))
  .where(array_contains($"textCol", "text1") ||
      array_contains($"textCol", "text2") ||
      array_contains($"textCol", "text3"))
```

Actually I wanted to make a generic api, If I go with option 2

then the problem is for every new text i need to add array_contains($"textCol", "text4") and create new api every time

and in option 1 it creates duplicate rows since I explode the array and also needs to drop the temporary column

Comment: use `array_contains` [check here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-collection.html)

Comment: @Yogesh Is there a way to pass multiple values in array_contains..I have not yet found on web

Comment: what do you mean by multiple values in array_contains ?

Comment: Seq("text1", "text2", "text3") if either of the one is in array then return true..So is there a way to pass like array_contains($"textCol",(text1", "text2", "text3")).. Like in clause

Comment: got it so this not possible in `array_contains` you can used any method mentioned in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`arrays_overlap`** (or) **`array_intersect`** functions to pass `array(<strings>)` instead of `array_contains`.

**`Example:`**
**`1.filter based on texts variable:`**

```
val df=Seq((Seq("text1")),(Seq("text4","text1")),(Seq("text5"))).
toDF("textCol")

df.show()
//+--------------+
//|       textCol|
//+--------------+
//|       [text1]|
//|[text4, text1]|
//|       [text5]|
//+--------------+

val texts = Array("text1","text2","text3")

//using arrays_overlap    
df.filter(arrays_overlap(col("textcol"),lit(texts))).show(false)
//+--------------+
//|textCol       |
//+--------------+
//|[text1]       |
//|[text4, text1]|
//+--------------+

//using arrays_intersect    
df.filter(size(array_intersect(col("textcol"),lit(texts))) > 0).show(false)
//+--------------+
//|textCol       |
//+--------------+
//|[text1]       |
//|[text4, text1]|
//+--------------+
```

**`2.Adding texts variable to the dataframe:`**

```
val texts = "text1,text2,text3"

val df=Seq((Seq("text1")),(Seq("text4","text1")),(Seq("text5"))).
toDF("textCol").
withColumn("texts",split(lit(s"${texts}"),","))

df.show(false)
//+--------------+---------------------+
//|textCol       |texts                |
//+--------------+---------------------+
//|[text1]       |[text1, text2, text3]|
//|[text4, text1]|[text1, text2, text3]|
//|[text5]       |[text1, text2, text3]|
//+--------------+---------------------+

//using array_intersect
df.filter("""size(array_intersect(textcol,texts)) > 0""").show(false)
//+--------------+---------------------+
//|textCol       |texts                |
//+--------------+---------------------+
//|[text1]       |[text1, text2, text3]|
//|[text4, text1]|[text1, text2, text3]|
//+--------------+---------------------+

//using arrays_overlap
df.filter("""arrays_overlap(textcol,texts)""").show(false)
+--------------+---------------------+
|textCol       |texts                |
+--------------+---------------------+
|[text1]       |[text1, text2, text3]|
|[text4, text1]|[text1, text2, text3]|
+--------------+---------------------+
```